# How to add an item in a list with .append conditionally in a loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

It should be easy, but I can't.

If the number is in the list return `True` but if not add the number to the list.

```
i=4
list=[2,3,5]
def check(i,list):
    if i in list:
        return True
    else:
        return list.append(i)
print (list)
```

The result that I want: `[2,3,5,4]`

The result that I have: `[2,3,5]`

Comment: You never call your function.

Comment: `if` is not a loop. You may be under the assumption that `list.append` returns the updated list; it doesn't. It's not clear why you would choose to return `True` or `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not call the function, so I added a line calling the function right before the print. I also changed a code to make the function simpler.

More importantly, you should avoid to use pre-defined keyword such as `list` (see https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keyword-list). I changed the variable name to l, instead of `list`.

```
i = 4
l = [2, 3, 5]


def check(i, l):
    if i not in l:
        #return l.append(i) # It works, but you do not need to return the list.
        l.append(i) # It also works.

check(i, l)
print(l)
# [2, 3, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

The list is not updating because you never call your function.
You should call your function at least once to add the number "4".

If you really need to return a boolean, you can do like so:

```
    number = 4
    number_list = [2, 3, 5]
    
    
    def check_number_in_list(number, number_list):
        if number in number_list:
            number_list.append(i)
            return True
        return False
    
    check_number_in_list(number, number_list)
    print(number_list)
```